# How to convert an Iterable to a js.Dynamic

Tags: scala.js

I have some optional parameters I want to use to initialise a JQuery widget that are passed as

```scala
Iterable[(String, String)]
```

What is the best way to convert this object to a `js.Dynamic`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the following:

```
val seq = iterable.toSeq
val dict = js.Dictionary(seq: _*)
val dynamic = dict.asInstanceOf[js.Dynamic]
```

You can of course make it into a single expression:

```
js.Dictionay(iterable.toSeq: _*).asInstanceOf[js.Dynamic]
```

Comment: When you do that, how to avoid hitting error "applyDynamic does not support passing a vararg parameter"? https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/9308 ? Also, it seems one can write `js.Dictionay(iterable.toSeq)` - why is that?